# How do I fix 503 errors deploying a Create React Application through Laravel on Cloudways?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, laravel, create-react-app

I am trying to launch a CRA hosted on a Cloudways Laravel app.  I've got a good build, I can run just as well on a local dev server, even when I'm SSH'd into the server and serving it from there.  I've set my htaccess as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /reactweb/build/index.html [L]

    # Redirect traffic to your port 3000
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:3000/$1 [P,L]
</IfModule>
```

I've got got a route built out in routes/web.php as follows:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

Route::get('/reactweb/{any}', function () {
    $indexFile = File::get(public_path('reactweb/build/index.html'));
    return Response::make($indexFile, 200);
})->where('any', '.*');
```

I'm at a complete loss why I'm getting 503 errors.  Contacted Cloudways and they thought that installing the Laravel Vite plugin would do it, but I don't see how it would, when CRA comes standard with WebPack.  Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!!!

I've tried doing a node_modules delete and npm install, I've tried as many variations of my htaccess as I can think of, I've tried mounting the CRA in a blade, I've made multiple copies of my htaccess and build files to see if I could maybe serve them from a different location (like the CRA root folder), I'm reset the server and cleared all the caches out...I'm just at a complete loss here.